# Is there a simple proof that there are no "off-by-1" solutions to Fermat's Last Theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$x^p + y^p = z^p$ has no integral solutions for $p>2$ due to the work of Andrew Wiles and others. My questions is: consider cases where $p>2$ and $y=x+1$ and $z=x+2$. We might call these "off-by-1" solutions. Is there any simple proof that there are no such off-by-1 solutions? (Admittedly, simple is somewhat subjective.)

Comment: From the title I thought you were looking for $x^p+y^p=z^p\pm1$, which _does_ have solutions (but probably finitely many).

Comment: $x=-1$ for an even $p$ gives $(-1)^p+(-1+1)^p=(-1+2)^p$ which is always true. This doesn't run counter to Fermat's last theorem, but it shows that simply working in $mod\ p$ or $mod\ x+1$ might not be enough for a simple proof.

Comment: Do you mean to restrict $p$ to be prime?  It matters here because of the restrictions on $x,y,z$, whereas in FLT the case where $p$ is prime (or $4$) implies the general case.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a comment until I work out the even-$p$ case. Work modulo $x+1$ so $(-1)^p \equiv 1$. This refutes all cases with odd $p$. If $p$ is even $a=x^q,\,b:=(x+1)^q,\,c:=(x+2)^q$ is a Pythagorean triple with $q:=p/2$. I'm still trying to force a contradiction. Since $c-b>b-a$, $a^2=c^2-b^2>(c+b)(b-a)>(3b-a)(b-a)=a^2+4b(b-a)-b^2>a^2-b^2$.

Comment: $(3b-a)(b-a) = a^2 + 3b^2 - 4ab = a^2 + 4b(b-a) - b^2$. Should be salvageable, but needs a correction.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well-spotted. I'm still working out how to do it.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer . Does there exist an even $n\geq 4$ and an odd $ j $ with $1\leq j\leq n-1$ such that $\binom {n}{j}$ is odd? If not then the case of an even $p\geq 4$  is easy.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet No, if $n$ is even and $j$ odd, then there is always a carry in the [base-$2$] addition $j + (n -j)$, so $\binom{n}{j}$ is then even.

Comment: @Piquito Is it obvious that $x+1\nmid 3^p-2^p-1$?

Comment: @J. G. It is not for $x=1$

Comment: @Danie Fischer .I withdraw my claim that I have an easy proof when   $p$ is even . I made a mistake

Comment: @Daniel Wainfleet: In fact, it is not easy. Do not forget that just in 1977, Terjanian proved FLT for even exponent, which in implicitly would mean that the Pythagorean triples are useless in this. On the other hand,  we must not lose sight of the fact that we do not have properly a Diophantine equation here but a simple algebraic equation in one incognita.

Comment: @Piquito.  In my head I considered the Binomial expansions on the RHS of $y^{2n}=(y+1)^{2n}+(y-1)^{2n}$ and mis-calculated something.... I once read that some 19th-century professor received so many amateur attempts on FLT that he had a "form letter" for them: "You have an error on Page ___, Line ___ ."

Comment: @Piquito . I don't understand what result of Terjanian you are describing. To prove FLT it suffices to consider odd prime $n$  and the  elementary case $n=4,$  and I suppose you already know this.

Comment: @Daniel Wainfleet: Terjanian’s paper “Sur l’équation $x^{2p}+y^{2p}=z^{2p}$" (Comptes Rendues, Academie des Sciences de Paris /1977) proves the first case ($n\nmid xyz$), less difficult than the second case ($n|xyz$) of theorem for even exponent. On the other hand the problem here could be the simplest particular case of a general proof, quite before Wiles, when x,y, z are in arithmetic

Comment: progression (successively discovered by K. Goldziber, by M. Mihaljinec and by D. Ramaver Rao). With these precedents and many others, it results from an almost soulful  ingenuity to try to use the Pythagorean triples in this problem (perhaps it could work but  because it is the simplest case of arithmetic progression already demonstrated in its generality before Wiles-Taylor. Actually it is a simple difficult equation in one unknown).

Answer (score 2):

Let's anchor it at the middle term, so that we're looking for integers $p > 2$ and $y$ such that

$$(y - 1)^p + y^p = (y + 1)^p. \tag{1}$$

[J.G.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/56861/j-g) elegantly disposed of the case where $p$ is odd, then reducing $(1)$ modulo $y$ yields

$$-1 = (-1)^p \equiv (y - 1)^p + y^p = (y + 1)^p \equiv 1^p = 1 \pmod{y}\,.$$

This congruence is satisfied only for $y \mid 2$, i.e. $y \in \{ -2,-1,1,2\}$, and one easily checks that none of these options gives a solution of $(1)$.

For even $p$, $y = 0$ yields the only solution. For $y < 0$ and even $p$ we have

$$(y - 1)^p + y^p = (\lvert y\rvert + 1)^p + \lvert y\rvert^p > \lvert y\rvert^p > (\lvert y\rvert - 1)^p = (y + 1)^p,$$

so it remains to rule out positive $y$. For $y \in \{1,2\}$ and $p > 1$ we always have

$$(y - 1)^p + y^p < (y + 1)^p,$$

hence in the following we assume $y > 2$. If $(1)$ were satisfied, then by the binomial theorem

$$y^p = (y + 1)^p - (y - 1)^p = 2\sum_{k = 1}^{p/2} \binom{p}{2k-1} y^{2k-1} = 2py + y^3\sum_{k = 2}^{p/2} \binom{p}{2k-1}y^{2k-4}\,.$$

The left hand side is divisible by $y^3$ (since $p > 2$), and the right hand side is divisible by $y^3$ if and only if $y^2 \mid 2p$. We thus obtain the necessary condition $p \geqslant \frac{1}{2}y^2$. But then we have

$$\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{y}\biggr)^p + 1 < 2 < 1 + \frac{y}{2} \leqslant 1 + \frac{p}{y} \leqslant \biggl(1 + \frac{1}{y}\biggr)^p$$

by Bernoulli's inequality.

Thus for $p > 2$ the equation $x^p + y^p = z^p$ has no nontrivial solutions with $x,y,z$ being consecutive integers.

Comment: I have been studying the same approach to the problem but I have not come up with your last reasoning. I try to prove that the resulting equation do not have integer solution (the thing is going very well for $p = 4$ in that the single solution is close to 8.121). Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy (and nice!) to discard $p$ odd (*look at the J.G.'s answer*) because of $(-1)^p\equiv 1\mod{(x+1)}$ impossible for $x\gt1$ and because the equation $1+2^p=3^p$ can be easily discarded so we consider just $p=4n$ and $p=4n+2$.

It is well known the periodicity modulo $4$ of classes modulo $10$. We have modulo $10$ the following table
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4&5&6&7&8&9&0 \\\hline x^2  & 1 & 4 &9&6&5&6&9&4&1&0\\\hline x^4 &1 &6  &1&6&5&6&1&6&1&0\\\hline\end{array}$$ It follows

► for $p\equiv 2\pmod4$.
$$\begin{cases}1^2+2^2=3^2\Rightarrow5\equiv9\pmod{10}\\2^2+3^2=4^2\Rightarrow3\equiv6\pmod{10}\\3^2+4^2=5^2\Rightarrow5\equiv5\pmod{10}\\4^2+5^2=6^2\Rightarrow1\equiv6\pmod{10}\\5^2+6^2=7^2\Rightarrow1\equiv9\pmod{10}\\6^2+7^2=8^2\Rightarrow5\equiv4\pmod{10}\\7^2+8^2=9^2\Rightarrow3\equiv1\pmod{10}\\8^2+9^2=0^2\Rightarrow5\equiv0\pmod{10}\\0^2+1^2=2^2\Rightarrow1\equiv4\pmod{10}\end{cases}$$
(*This can be written directly from the table but has been made explicit for beginners*).

We see that WLG we can proved just the impossibility of
$$(10m+3)^{4n+2}+(10m+4)^{4n+2}=(10m+5)^{4n+2}.....\space\space (*)$$
►for $p\equiv 0\pmod4$.

Similarly we should try only the equation
$$(10m+5)^{4n}+(10m+6)^{4n}=(10m+7)^{4n}.....\space\space (**)$$

So we have reduced the problem to just proving  $(*)$ and $(**)$. I stop here until a new attempt and maybe someone can prove beforehand the impossibility of these two equations for which the Pythagorean triples could be perhaps a good way.